# Can we have a spell-check and grammar-check to improve posts?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, grammar

Can we have a spell-checker and grammar-checker on Math.SE ? so that could fix all the errors that some users have because they are not native english speakers. Whether on their questions, answers, comments, etc. about mathematics.

I think we all have observed the grammar mistakes that lots of posts have, since the beginning of Math.stack. See for instance an attempt to fix this problem: [Should we have an FAQ with basic math-specific English?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6418/should-we-have-an-faq-with-basic-math-specific-english) from 2012. The last comment (yiyi's comment) in that link suggested a "spell check" feature when submitting a question or answer.

I think that would improve a lot Math.stack.

There will  be no more grammar/spell mistakes when posting a question/answer/... from now on, none of us would have the need to edit such grammar/spell mistakes from now on, we could take the *correctly written posts* as an example* to fix all previous posts.

---

example*

I once edited a title of a question using *convergence of* when it should have been used *convergence for*, but I chose *of* because I based my edit on an older question's title that was linked to it..

**EDIT**

Considering some remarks from Roddy MacPhee's answer,

1. Maybe the checker should *not fix* the 'wrong' word but *suggest to fix* the 'wrong' word. (underlying, with a different color and not with a straight line, the suspicious word).
2. This feature could also have: punctuation-checker.
3. Regarding the english dialectic, could be American english or British english, as a community we could vote to chose one of them.

Considering URL's comment,

This feature should not be considered as 'you must have it' but as an optional feature, so that it can be *turned on* or *turned off* at any time.

Comment: Checking spelling is one thing, checking grammar strikes me as being several orders of magnitude more difficult. Is there any software that comes standard with a grammar checker?

Comment: Some related discussions can be found in [meta.se] question [Please add a spell checker to the Markdown editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3932) and some of the [posts linked there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/3932). These ones touch also on grammar: [Spellchecker / grammar checker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165970), [Automatic grammar fixing in questions and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277886).

Comment: Well intentioned, but this might come out as invasive.

Comment: @URL invasive? what do you exactly mean?

Comment: @MartinSleziak thank you for the information. I definitely need to check Meta Stack Exchange before asking here

Comment: @GerryMyerson I don't know. But I think there should be one that detects and suggest to fix both issues on Math.stack

Comment: @ellisaba People generally don’t like being corrected, even though they’re wrong.

Comment: @URL I really doubt that someone wouldn't like to see their own post looking good respect to the grammar and spelling.

Comment: @ellisaba Of course, but forcing it isn’t likely to be well received. Moreover, if someone has a poor enough grasp on English, an autocorrect might be more annoying than helpful.

Comment: @URL you're right. This could be an optional feauture such that it can activated or deactivated.

Answer (score 1):

A few road blocks :

- Different dialects of English
- Correcting to the wrong word
- MathJaX `\text` command
- Markdown markers
- Different math contexts
- Punctuation check needed
- Compute intensive string searching
- etc.

I've made a FaR script in PARI GP before. It's not fun, and grammar is more complicated.